# Arcpro 3.1 won't convert to "global scene" - GISLounge tutorial

Tags: gis, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working through this GISLounge tutorial:
https://www.gislounge.com/map-buildings-2-5d-arcgis-pro/

I'm using Arcpro 3.1. [screenshot of how it looks after I convert to map global scene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFVG2.jpg)

I moved through all the steps of the tutorial with ease, except for deleting uneccessary attributes in QGIS before saving the layer as a shapefile. The attribute table at that point was filled in with "NULL" values so I chose not to delete anything at that point.

I carried on and all went smooth and quick. Once I added the shapefile into Arcpro, I went to catalogue, right-clicked, chose 'convert', chose 'to global scene'. Yet, unlike the tutorial screenshot, my Arc screen did not change into 'global scene'. I tried various things but none worked.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You might find also https://gis.stackexchange.com/ useful for searching answers.